# How to add animations in webgi using Gsap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, gsap

How to add trigger on canvas using Webgi and Gsap.

I want to add a trigger on my Model inside the Canvas such that whenver the canvas comes in frame  it should be on lets say x y z axis , and then when the user scrolls the model should trigger and zoom in to x` y z and then stay there till 200vh scroll. after then it should move to another components.
Im currently unable to set the correct postition of the model inside canvas as well as how to stop the canvas for 200vh scrolls.

Here is my code for ref.

```
export default function Wrapper() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const memoizedScrollAnimatiom = useCallback((position, target, onUpdate) => {
    if (position && onUpdate && target) {
      ScrollAnimation(position, target, onUpdate);
    }
  }, []);
  const setupViewer = useCallback(async () => {
    const viewer = new ViewerApp({
      canvas: canvasRef.current,
    });
    const manager = await viewer.addPlugin(AssetManagerPlugin);
    const camera = viewer.scene.activeCamera;
    var position = camera.position;
    const target = camera.target;
    await viewer.addPlugin(GBufferPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(new ProgressivePlugin(32));
    await viewer.addPlugin(new TonemapPlugin(true));
    await viewer.addPlugin(GammaCorrectionPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(SSRPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(SSAOPlugin);
    await viewer.addPlugin(BloomPlugin);
    console.log(position);
    viewer.renderer.refreshPipeline();
    var needsUpdate = true;
    const onUpdate = () => {
      needsUpdate = true;
      viewer.setDirty();
    };
    await manager.addFromPath("../../assets/Desktop/scene.glb");
    viewer.getPlugin(TonemapPlugin).config.clifBackground = true;
    viewer.scene.activeCamera.setCameraOptions({ controlsEnabled: false });
    viewer.addEventListener("preFrame", () => {
      if (needsUpdate) {
        camera.positionUpdated(true);
        needsUpdate = false;
      }
    });
    memoizedScrollAnimatiom(position, target, onUpdate);
    console.log(position);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    setupViewer();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Section>
      <div id="webGi">
        <canvas
          id="webGi-canvas"
          className="webgiCanva"
          ref={canvasRef}
        ></canvas>
      </div>
      <div className="gradient-background">
       <Hero/>
      </div>
    </Section>
  );
}
```

here is my gsap animation file

```
import gsap from "gsap";

export const ScrollAnimation = (position, target, onUpdate) => {
  const tl1 = gsap.timeline();
  tl1
    .to(position, {
      x: 8.7109187797,
      y: 1.1866802099,
      z: -0.2344851352,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".webgiCanva",
        start: "top bottom",
        end: "bottom top",
        scrub: 2,
        immediateRender: false,
      },
      onUpdate,
    })
    .to(target, {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".webgiCanva",
        start: "top bottom",
        end: " bottom top",
        scrub: 2,
        immediateRender: false,
      },
    }); 
};
```